# Multiple Full Text Search SQL Queries Merged and Scored (Ranked Search Results)

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I have a bunch of articles in one table that I'd like to query for search results. Using Full Text Search I can return a list of items that have the search keywords "near" each other.

Full text search does not seem to allow thesaurus (FORMSOF) with the NEAR delimiter.

What I'd like to do, in SQL, is create a query, or a number of queries, which search the same data, in different ways, and return a score (or RANK if using Full Text Search), then I would like to merge these results so there are no duplicates, and total up the ranks/scores, so that I can ORDER BY those scores.

Add in that I would also like to search a separate link table of "tags" that the documents have been assigned, and also assign extra score for those with corresponding tags.

What is the best practice way of fulfilling these requirements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Full-text search can do search like `('"word*" near "another*"')` in  `CONTAINSTABLE` statement. The asterisk will help to search any words started with `'word'` and `'another'` near each other with ranking.

On the other side you can launch `FORMSOF(Thesaurus, word) AND FORMSOF(Thesaurus, another)` search with `CONTAINSTABLE` statement.

Then MERGE the results and use ORDER BY to sort by both given RANKs.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
I was stuck with this for a while, but realised that i could write specific queries for the different search results, for example one set of results for "word" near "another" and then formsof(thesaurus, word) by Performing nested queries that are UNION'd and then group by the results and SUM'ing the total RANK.

It may not be the most elegant solution, but it's scalable and works quickly.

Comment: My pleasure! Great if it helps and great that you find a solution!